# Call to a member function View() on null

Tags: php, smarty

My IF in this method forward to view variable `$this->session['stCeneo']`.

```
public function onCheckoutPostDispatch(\Enlight_Event_EventArgs $args)
    {
        $this->subject = $args->getSubject();


   if ('finish' === $this->subject->Request()->getActionName()) {
            $this->saveRequestToSession();

            $view = $subject->View(); //error?
            $view->assign('stCeneo', $this->session['stCeneo']); //error?

        }
```

`$this->session['stCeneo']` is implemented in `saveRequestToSession()`.

```
private function saveRequestToSession()
{
    if ($this->subject->Request()->getParam('stOpineo') !== null) {
        $this->session['stOpineo'] = $this->subject->Request()->getParam('stOpineo') ? true : false;
    }

    if ($this->subject->Request()->getParam('stCeneo') !== null) {
        $this->session['stCeneo'] = $this->subject->Request()->getParam('stCeneo') ? true : false;
    }
}
```

SO I don't know, why I have a error in my line commented:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function View() on null

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I resolved this problem. I write:

```
$this->subject->View()->assign('stCeneo', $this->session['stCeneo']);
```